# Override XmlRoot attribute defined in dataset designer class

Tags: c#, serialization, dataset

I have a dataset named DocumentDataSet along with a class named Document.

When the dataset is serialized, I need it to have it root named "Document" because I'm communicating with a 3rd party webservice.

I though of defining the attribute `XmlRoot` in the partial class of the dataset, but I cannot add a duplicate of XmlRoot since it is already defined in the designer class.

```
[global::System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute("DocumentDataSet")]
public partial class DocumentDataSet : global::System.Data.DataSet { ... }
```

I could change it in the designer class, but it get reset every time I open the dataset in design.

Is there is a way to override `XmlRoot` or make it serialize with a different name that its class name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [XmlSerializer constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1wczcys.aspx) that accepts an `XmlRootAttribute` which represents the XML root element to be used.

```
new XmlSerializer(typeof(DocumentDataSet), new XmlRootAttribute("Document"));
```

It's also possible to do something like this:

```
class DocumentDataSet : DataSet
{
    public new string GetXml()
    {
        return base.GetXml().Replace("DocumentDataSet ", "Document");
    }
}
```

If you end up with this approach a simple `Replace` is not enough, but this is just for illustration purposes. Also be advised that if you reference your document data set instances by the base class `DataSet` this last approach won't work.

```
DataSet ds = new DocumentDataSet();

ds.GetXml(); // Wrong
```

Comment: So, I should override at the moment I serialize? sound ok

Comment: Yes, when serializing the `DocumentDataSet` you should override the root element as specified in the example.

Comment: That would make us change all our GetXml to using a serializer object instead. It is doable, but requires a lot of work.. urk..